# In Inception movie final scene, why does the spinning top never comes to rest?

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

In Inception movie climax, why does the director cut to black before the spinning top is shown coming to rest?

Comment: It doesn't definitely show it 'never coming to rest' - it cuts to black leaving the ending somewhat uncertain.

Comment: I also somewhat agree with @Paulster2 - it is somewhat addressed in the other question.  Is there some other aspect of that final scene that you are uncertain of?

Comment: @iandotkelly Well, when asking *why* it is left ambiguous, it is indeed a different question than the duplicate (though, I'm sure the answers there also adress this already anyway).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - well the OP asked why the top never stopped,  I've pushed the question in the direction of the ambiguity, and why it was left that way. It may not be what danishkumar intended.

Comment: Ideally it could have been cut before the wobble appears on the top. A wobble happens only when there is a change in speed. That should be enough indication. I doubt it can never come to rest given a clear wobble.

Answer (score -3):

I like to think that with all the unanswered questions this ending leaves behind, Nolan is leaving us wanting more and hinting at a sequel to resolve the ending.
I think most people believe it did fall, but Nolan is teasing us with the continued idea of these layered dreams, and trying to lure you into a dreamworld of your own.
He might want you to make the decision for yourself - whether or not it did fall... although, do you really want a solid hollywood ending where they all live happily ever after, not really. Because the whole point about this movie (and why you like it enough to ask questions about it) is that it is layered and complicated which works in its favour to allow it to finish how it did.
Therefore it could just be another cliffhanger that will never get resolved on screen, like lost or cube, these endings annoy us so much we are still celebrating and re-watching our re-watches of them, whether it's a film or programme, 10+ years later. (sorry to finish on that note, had to be done) [fade to black]